# How to trigger Lambda directly by whatever process is putting the message into SQS(not via scheduled events)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I created lambda function. By default no trigger for sqs. I create Rules in CloudWatch and chose `Event Pattern` -> `Service Name: SQS`, `Event Type: All Events`. To the tab `Targets` chose my lambda function and create configuration. After, to my function added this trigger, but not react to add message in SQS queue. Please, help me. Why not react? How to create lambda without `Cron`?

Comment: What is generating the SQS message? Why do you wish to send a message to SQS?

Comment: SQS is a cheap and simple message queue system, it doesn't do triggering at the moment. And why you want to put stuff in SQS when you can make Cloudwatch to trigger the lambda works?

Comment: @mootmoot SNS unreliable system

Answer (score 1):

Queues are designed to store messages for future processing, but the benefit of AWS Lambda is that it can *immediately* run code rather than having to wait.

Rather than trying to trigger an AWS Lambda function from Amazon SQS, you should trigger Lambda directly by whatever process is *putting* the message into SQS. That process should call Lambda directly or it could send a message via **Amazon SNS**, which is capable of triggering a Lambda function.

Your current process of `SQS -> CloudWatch -> Alarm -> Lambda` does not send the original SQS message to Lambda. Instead, it sends details of the CloudWatch Alarm (which does not contain the message).

Rather than trying to workaround the fact that SQS cannot trigger Lambda, try to design the application so that it does not require SQS at all.

Comment: The app is large and i cannot be refused from sqs. How to invoke Lambda by whatever process is putting the message into SQS? please, help me

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot be refused"? Are you saying that there is no way to change the app so that it sends to SNS instead of SQS?

Comment: it's not my project, I'm just working on it, therefore I cannot answer this question. Could you please tell me, how to invoke Lambda by whatever process is putting the message into SQS? Please, tell me. I have not found an answer

Comment: It is YOUR process that is sending a message to SQS. That is, something in your application is pushing a message into an SQS queue. Instead of sending a message to SQS, you could change your application to send it to SNS or to call Lambda directly.